# how to grab input/select information and then print database information from there. Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, php, html

so no code I was just wondering if this was possible to do before I start it. So I'm going to make one php page. So no submit form with action to another php page.

On that page it will have the user type or select login information (id, pass, name etc). Below the login info I was grab the information from the above part to figure out which database they have access to and print the list of database they have access to in a html/php table.

So would this be possible to do in one page. Or do I need to make a form (to grab their information). And then from there print the list of database the user has access to. If it is possible how hard is it I'm pretty new to programming just finished HS. Will you guys be able to guide/point me in the right direction. Much help would be appreciated

Comment: Where will the user type if they aren't using a form?  Either way, you will need to extract some input, correct?

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking here!

Comment: You cannot log someone into your system without asking them who they are!! Unless I am missing something here you will need a form

Comment: thanks. I am no trying to log them in. I just need their id to run a query. to see which database they have access to. But i need their login info to grab the database access they have

Comment: So I could be a hacker and just make up `id's` till I find one that works?? Still not very clear

Comment: And how are you going to let a user tell you what their ID is without a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to connect to db at top of page (or better in another file and require it)
so you can do sth like that
db.ph:

```
<?php

$host = '';
$dbuser = '';
$paswrd = '';
$dbname = '';
$dns = 'mysql:host=' . $host .'; dbname=' . $dbname;
try 
{
    $pdo = new PDO($dns, $dbuser, $paswrd);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  //  echo "polaczono z mysql";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
   // echo "nie udało się połączenie: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

next in login page you do:

```
require('db.php');


if(isset( $_POST['login']))
{
    require('./config/db.php');


    /*
    $userName = $_POST['userName'];
    $userEmail = $_POST['password'];
    */

    $userName = filter_var( $_POST['userName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $userPassword = filter_var( $_POST['userPassword'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  

    $stmt = $pdo -> prepare('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE name =?');
    $stmt -> execute([$userName]);
    $user = $stmt ->fetch();}
```

and you can check if its correct for example if($user->password==$userPassword)

and in html:

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="userName">Name</label>        
                    <input required type="text" name="userName" ">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="userPassword">Password</label>
                <input required type="password" name="userPassword"/>
            </div>
            <button name="login" type="submit" >Login</button>
```

Comment: And as you want everything in one page this will be mess but you can. just dont use require. You can go with <?php if(sth) ?> and show what you want bassed on user id or whateverr

Comment: So you are suggesting the use of plain text passwords... Right?

Comment: Of course no, but he was asking if he can do it on one page. Hashing is diffrent subject.